# Getting all audio files in a directory on android?

Tags: android

I'm using the following code to get all audio files (actually their ids so I can play them later with `MediaPlayer`) from a directory on my android device:

```
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
Uri audioUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(dir.getPath()); //dir is a File object representing the dir I'm looking in
Cursor audioCursor = cr.query(audioUri, null, null, null, null);

if (audioCursor != null && audioCursor.moveToFirst()) {
    int idColumn = audioCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);

    List<Long> fileIds = new ArrayList<>();
    do {
        long id = audioCursor.getLong(idColumn);
        fileIds.add(id);
    } while (audioCursor.moveToNext());

    return fileIds;
} else { 
    return null;
}
```

For some reason however, it returns an array with 2904 ids for any dir I give it. I'm guessing there are 2904 audio files on my device (when I use `Uri audioUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` it also returns 2904 ids). So it seems I'm using `getContentUriForPath` incorrectly, however the [android reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.Media.html#getContentUriForPath%28java.lang.String%29) doesn't give any information.

How should this work?

*Some more info about what I'm trying to do (if it makes any difference in your answer): I'm still working on the code, trying out different things. Ultimately I want to play the files with `MediaPlayer`. I only need the audio files in that folder directly, ignoring any subfolders. They should also be ordered by filename.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `getContentUriForPath` with a folder, there isn't any content registered at this path. In this case `getContentUriForPath` return the standard `EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`, for this reason you get all the ids available.

This return all the files contained in a particular folder (e.g. `/storage/emulated/0/Music/`), ignoring any subfolders and ordered by filename:

```
Cursor audioCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " LIKE ? AND " + MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " NOT LIKE ?",
                new String[]{path + "%", path + "%/%"},
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");

if (audioCursor != null && audioCursor.moveToFirst()) {
    int idColumn = audioCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);

    List<Long> fileIds = new ArrayList<>();
    do {
        long id = audioCursor.getLong(idColumn);
        fileIds.add(id);
    } while (audioCursor.moveToNext());

    return fileIds;
} else { 
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Aha, makes sense. That indeed explains why I just get everything. They should really add this to the documentation. Also thanks very much for the code, I think I'm starting to understand this query and cursor stuff :D

Comment: Ok, finally got around to testing it properly. It works, though I had to make sure my "path" variable ends with a "/", which it didn't when I used `dir.getPath()`. Thanks! (Sorry btw for unaccepting your answer, misclicked and didn't notice immediately.)

One more question though, I'm using this for an audio-book app I'm making, so I wanted to add a `.nomedia` file to the root folder of the audiobooks (so other music players don't show them as just music files), but then the contentResolver can't find the files anymore it seems, which makes sense. But is there a way around this?

Comment: @Mattia I'm using your code in Android 10 and it's working fine, but I'm accessing a folder I created programmatically. For some reason the cursor only reads the files in the folder if I move a file into the folder using the device using a File Manager app. It seems that after moving a file into the folder the permission of the folder changes and the Cursor is able to read the files, any tips why it's happening?