# Xamarin Forms, Android 11+, Access music folder in root

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, mp3, android-permissions

Hi i searched and searched.

How do i access the music folder in android? **Not** the music folder of the app.

Android.OS is not available.

I even tried System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("/"); no permissions.

I checked every permission in the manifest that states storage or read.

I need the filepath to each audio file to be able to play it. I don't need a file dialog where the user chooses a file.

I need a string[] of all audio files in the root music dir not the app dir.

There has to be a way, cause audio players exist that access my root music folder.

**NOT** sdCard Storage

Comment: you can't access the device music library via the file system.  You have to use the appropriate platform APIs to do it.  You can access platform APIs using XF's DependencyService, or there may be existing plugins that will help you do what you need.

Comment: And how do you access the music folder? I need filepaths that i can use to play the file.

Comment: use and Android Media API

Comment: i dont see the relevant information. It does not what i need. I dont want a file dialog. I want access to all audio files in the root music dir programmatically.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69455935/how-do-i-get-data-about-all-audio-files-in-the-users-device-using-xamarin-andr

Comment: No access to MediaStore. And this example reads only sd card storage.

Comment: as I explained before, you will need to use DependencyService to access the Android APIs.  And I'm sure that you could modify the example to do what you need.

Comment: this is not helpful.

Comment: the linked question appears to do exactly what you want.  Have you actually tried it?  Just saying "not helpful" doesn't really explain where you're stuck.

Comment: the example is clearly for sdcard storage access. There are plenty of examples for that. But no working example for accessing the non-sdcard music storage.

Comment: use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.Media#INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

Comment: No access to MediaStore

Comment: You cannot use platform apis directly in shared code, as I have mentioned several times.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

Comment: ok i see what you mean, but how do i access the music? Service aside, how do i access the music in the plattform specific code?

Comment: [Xamarin Android Audio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/android-audio). (IF THAT doesn't give enough details, google `android dev mediaplayer play music`. THOSE docs and tutorials will be in java; but with that understanding, you can go to the corresponding xamarin.android classes, and do the same steps.) If you get stuck, add to question the code you are trying; explain what detail you are stuck on.

Comment: googling `android dev mediaplayer list all audio files programmatically`, I see [Getting all audio files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33575171/199364). And similar Q&As.

Comment: after trying a lot. I did not get access to the directories. I'll just work in the app directory. If you know how it works now( 2022 ) not years ago, give me a working example of accessing one audio file in the music dir of the root directory. in XAMARIN

Comment: like i said before not helpful!

Comment: Had you tried the code I provided?

Comment: as stated in the title. I'm trying to access the root dir not the dir in a sd card. I'm working in the app dir now since no one seems to know how u access the music root folder.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try to grant your app the permission about accessing all the files.

At first, add the permission into the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And then add the following code into the OnCreate method of the main activity to request the permission.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    LoadApplication(new App());
    if (!Android.OS.Environment.IsExternalStorageManager)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.SetAction(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionManageAppAllFilesAccessPermission);
        Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromParts("package", this.PackageName, null);
        intent.SetData(uri);
        StartActivity(intent);
    }
}
```